# Cloud SQL insert error when missing values/ big file

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am reading csv and inserting it into cloud sql using the following procedure:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', keep_default_na=False)

    ##  from field “world” remove C. , County , Cnty
    df['world'] = df['world'].str.rstrip('C.CountyCnty')

    ## connects to mysql database and adds the dataframe to it
    connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://xxxx:xxxx@xx.xxx.x.xx:aaaa/mydatabase'

    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=False)
    conn = engine.connect()
    df.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    conn.close()
```

However, this does safe inserts into SQL until it faces a file which starts with empty row value in the world field. NOTE: It does safe inserts for files which has empty rows which appears later.

I believe the error is occurring due to empty fields in the csv data. But I used  `keep_default_na=False` to fix it. But still it persists. Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is how the error looks like

```
 (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'xx.xxx.xx.x:aaaa', system error: 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: should `con=engine` not be `con=conn` ?

Comment: Why is it so? I don't have any connection related issues. I have problem with empty fields. I need a way to skip the rows that starts with empty fields. @GerardH.Pille

Comment: You don't consider a "Lost connection" to be connection related?

Comment: I see. Good point. Can u tell me when do we use con=engine and con=conn? I couldn't find anything related. Thanks for your reply.  @GerardH.Pille

Comment: I just found an example using the engine as con parameter,  But then I don't understand the use of the engine.connect().

Comment: Just read this: `With some databases, writing large DataFrames can result in errors due to packet size limitations being exceeded. This can be avoided by setting the chunksize parameter when calling to_sql. For example, the following writes data to the database in batches of 1000 rows at a time:`  `data.to_sql('data_chunked', engine, chunksize=1000)`

Comment: May be I should use chunksize?

Comment: It won't hurt!  Give it a try.

Comment: the chunksize solved the problem!! Thank you so much!!! @GerardH.Pille. you are a legend

Comment: Or I will be soon.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries :  With some databases, writing large DataFrames can result in errors due to packet size limitations being exceeded. This can be avoided by setting the chunksize parameter when calling to_sql. For example, the following writes data to the database in batches of 1000 rows at a time:

```
 data.to_sql('data_chunked', engine, chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: To be specific I used :
`df.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=1000)`

Thanks @Gerard